# How can I manually sync local files to icloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, mojave

For some reasons my local files are not sync'd to the icloud drive. I am still trying to figure out the root cause.

The icloud sync seems to have been stopped sometimes in Sep this year.

[image]

All newer files have the 'up' arrow under them in Icons view.  It means they have not been uploaded yet, for weeks.

I have made sure I have turned on all the related options

[image]

But the 'icloud drive' does not show any upload status message:

[image]

I wanted to try the 'sign out from icloud then sign in again'  trick but the message is not reassuring for me:

[image]

My local drive is too small to hold all archive data and it will definitely fail!

I am very reluctant to go down this route at this stage.

**My question:**

Is it possible to make a certain subfolder to sync to iCloud with some commands, hopefully similar to `rsync`?